Coil AsyncImage Not Displaying Image in Jetpack Compose – What Could Be Wrong?
I'm building an Android app using Jetpack Compose and Coil to display a profile image. I've used AsyncImage to load an image from a URL, but it’s not rendering anything on the screen.
Here’s my relevant code:
@Composable
fun ProfilePage(authViewModel: AuthViewModel) {

    var tempImageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }

    val profileImageUrl by authViewModel.profileImageUrl.collectAsState()

    val isUploading by authViewModel.isUploading.collectAsState()

    val context = LocalContext.current
    
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

        authViewModel.loadProfileImageUrl()

    }
    
    val galleryLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(

        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()

    ) { uri: Uri? ->

        uri?.let {

            tempImageUri = it

            authViewModel.uploadProfileImage(it)

        }

    }



    val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(

        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()

    ) { success: Boolean ->

        if (success) {

            tempImageUri?.let { authViewModel.uploadProfileImage(it) }

        }

    }



    Column(

        modifier = Modifier

            .fillMaxSize()

            .padding(16.dp),

        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally

    ) {

        Card(

            modifier = Modifier

                .size(200.dp)

                .padding(8.dp)

        ) {

            if (isUploading) {

                androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }

            } else {
var lol = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/32.jpg";
                AsyncImage(

                    model = lol,

                    contentDescription = "Profile Image",

                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),

                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,

                    onLoading = { /* You can add a loading indicator here if needed */ },

                    onError = { /* You can add an error placeholder here if needed */ }

                )

            }

        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Row(

            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),

            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly

        ) {

            Button(onClick = { galleryLauncher.launch("image/*") }) {

                Text("Choose from Gallery")

            }


            Button(onClick = {

                val photoFile = File.createTempFile(

                    "profile_photo",

                    ".jpg",

                    context.cacheDir

                ).apply {

                    createNewFile()

                    deleteOnExit()

                }
                
                val photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(

                    context,

                    "${context.packageName}.fileprovider",

                    photoFile

                )

                tempImageUri = photoUri

                cameraLauncher.launch(photoUri)

            }) {

                Text("Take Photo")
            }
        }
    }
}

I’ve already added the required internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml:
However, the image still does not appear.
Here are a few things I tried:
Confirmed that the URL works directly in a browser.
Wrapped the AsyncImage in a Card with fixed size.
It works with local image but not url.

Try to add the ImageRequest on model parameter
var lol = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/32.jpg"
                AsyncImage(
                    model =
                        ImageRequest
                            .Builder(LocalContext.current)
                            .data(lol)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.generic_icon)
                            .dispatcher(Dispatchers.IO)
                            .build(),
                    contentDescription = "Profile Image",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                )

